# How do I edit RAW in Photos on iOS 10?

Tags: photos, photos.app, ios

In Photos on macOS it is clear when I am editing a RAW file:

- I need to explicitly choose *Image > Use RAW as Original*, and
- the type of the file (e.g., Raw vs JPEG) is clearly indicated in several places in the UI.

However Photos in iOS 10 lacks both these features.

How can I be sure I'm editing RAW in Photos on iOS 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an app from the App Store in order to both take photos in RAW as well as edit them. The two apps I am familiar with that do this are [Adobe Lightroom](https://appsto.re/us/EXsy0.i) and [Obscura Camera](https://appsto.re/us/u-bM2.i).

Comment: So Photos on iOS doesn't support RAW?

Comment: No, not at this time at least. The RAW capabilities are new APIs available to 12 MP cameras in iOS 10, not enhancements to the Photos app.

Comment: That makes sense. Editing RAW on such a tiny screen seems a bit silly anyway. I'd read in several places that Photos on iOS supported editing RAW, which was why I wondered at al; but looking back I see it was just sloppy writing.

Comment: Photos on iOS does support RAW. I took a RAW (not RAW+JPEG) photo in ProCamera, and Photos on iPhone does display it, and let me edit it. To verify that Photos is indeed displaying a RAW and not a JPEG, I shared the photo to Google Drive, and it was a .dng, not a .jpg.